# Resize UISwitch in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I would like to change the default size of the UISwitch in Swift 4.

I have looked at various options but they all relate to v3 and do not work.

Please can someone suggest an example that does so programmatically in Swift 4?

Thank you,

Edit:

I have tried the following examples:

```
 switchTest.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75)

 switchTest.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.75, y: 0.75)

 UISwitch *switchTest = [UISwitch new];
 switchTest.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75);
```

The error message that I received is always the same and says this:

> Expected declaration

Comment: Show what you have tried and explain what isn't working.

Comment: Please see my edit above, thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to use Objective-C code in your Swift code?

Comment: I am very new to Swift so my answer to that is that I do not know any better, my basic understanding is that they are very similar and I have only been looking at examples I can find online, hence the question I have posted.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Swift 4 Code**

**Method 1**

Drag UISwitch Storyboard. Make an outlet of your UISwitch and replace ViewDidLoad method by this code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var switchDemo: UISwitch!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   switchDemo.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.75, y: 0.75)
}
```

**Method 2**

Make UISwitch through programmatically.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let switchSwift4 = UISwitch(frame:CGRect(x: 150, y: 300, width: 0, height: 0))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.switchSwift4.isOn = true
        switchSwift4.setOn(true, animated: false)
        switchSwift4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchValueDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        switchSwift4.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.75, y: 0.75)
        self.view!.addSubview(switchSwift4)
    }

    @objc func switchValueDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if switchSwift4.isOn == true {
            print("On")
        }
        else {
            print("Off")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used method one and it works perfectly! Thank you so much Khawar, a beautifully simple solution and easy to follow.

Comment: You always Welcome Man