# How to fit a thumb to custom size switch?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiswitch

I'm working on the custom UISwitch. I have changed size using this: 
 self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.25, y: 1.16). 
And now I have one problem, the thumb is still default size.
[image]

How can I fit it with uiswitch?

```
class CustomSwitch:UISwitch {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.viewDidLoad()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func viewDidLoad() {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.25, y: 1.16)
        self.setupAppearance()
        self.setColors()
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleState), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    func setupAppearance() {
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.HavelockBlue.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.height / 2
    }

    func setColors() {
        self.backgroundColor = .white
        self.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.onTintColor = .white
        self.thumbTintColor = .HavelockBlue
    }

    @objc func toggleState() {
        if self.isOn {
            print("Dark mode is on")
        } else {
            print("Dark mode is off")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.25, y: 1.16)` Add code please *(edit your question)*

Comment: Whole implementation goes there -> https://imgur.com/A1V74LS

Comment: For what reason you have this line: `self.transform = .identity`? This will set default transformation

Comment: I've tried different methods from SOF and so on. Anyway, it doesn't work.

Comment: This code will work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040403/resize-uiswitch-in-swift-4

Comment: Are you using `IB`(auto layout) or creating your custom `CustomSwitch` using code?

Comment: I am using IB with sizes 64:36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, you settings **constrained** `width` and `height` for your custom `UISwitch`, and after then you are trying to `transform` this object, but what actually happen.

Inside this `override init(frame: CGRect)` and `required init?(coder: NSCoder)` methods if you using *auto layout* you don't have actually final size of your `UIView`, the size is taken from `IB`. But you are setting `self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.height / 2`. If you will print values of `frame.size and bounds.size` you will see.

Simple solution is to remove constrained sizes from `IB` and just `transform` to your desire scale.

---

Example:

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    changeSwitchSize()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    changeSwitchSize()
}

private func changeSwitchSize() {
    print("Before transform switch frame size: \(frame.size), bounds size: \(bounds.size)")
    self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.25, y: 1.16)
    print("After transform switch frame size: \(frame.size), bounds size: \(bounds.size)")
}

/// Before transform switch frame: (51.0, 31.0), (51.0, 31.0)
/// After transform switch frame: (63.75, 35.95999999999998), (51.0, 31.0)
```

> But be aware than `CGAffineTransform` change view's frame relative to its superview

More about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11288488/6057764

Comment: I got it! Thanks a lot. The problem was very simple, width and height constraints were needless.